# Python selenium cannot click or change value in radio button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to automate amazon affiliate report generation. cannot change the value of a checkbox

[need to mark this checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8yJl.png)

[this is HTML of that checkbok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FydHz.png)

```
radio = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//input[@value='custom' and @name='ac-daterange-radio-report-download-timeInterval']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radio)

# driver.execute_script(
#     "arguments[0].setAttribute('checked', 'checked';", radio)
```

If more clarity needed can ask here.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending click event to java script executor, instead of this you directly click by `.click()` method. If you want to click one of the checkbox you use one of the following commands, change the text contains: Today,  Yesterday and other. See this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Today')]/ancestor::label/input").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Yesterday')]/ancestor::label/input").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Custom Date Range')]/ancestor::label/input").click()
```

Comment: I'm getting 

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: @SamJoshuva can you add the html code to the question. Also which checkbox do you want to check?

Comment: <div id="ac-daterange-radio-report-download-timeInterval-custom" data-a-input-name="ac-daterange-radio-report-download-timeInterval" class="a-radio a-radio-fancy" aria-checked="false">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="ac-daterange-radio-report-download-timeInterval" value="custom">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-radio a-icon-radio-inactive"></i>
<span class="a-label a-radio-label">Custom Date Range
</span>
</label>
</div>

Comment: which checkbox do you want to click?

Comment: @SamJoshuva this seem correct, can you add full html of the checkbox div

Comment: Anyone has done amazon affiliate report automation with custom date range filters

Comment: @SamJoshuva this is very broad question hence none could help you. Put the complete HTML and explain what you can't do specifically.